# merging structured encrypted data

Tags: encryption, cryptography

I wanted to know if there is a way to merge bencoded data (or otherwise structured data), encrypted.

i.e. you have something like this

```
{
   "comment": "Big Buck Bunny, Sunflower version"
}
```

which bencoded looks like this

```
bencode1 = d7:comment33:Big Buck Bunny, Sunflower versione
```

You encrypt this, with I am not too sure what, or even if this kind of cryptography exists.
You get some encrypted content, let's call it `encrypted1 = encrypt(bencode1)`

From somewhere else, you get `encrypted2 = encrypt(bencoded2)`. You don't know what bencoded2 is, just the encrypted result of it.
Somehow, I'd like to know if there is way to get:

```
encrypted_merge = merge(encrypted1,encrypted2)
```

Having myself the decrypt function, I would be able to do

```
merge_result = decrypt(encrypted_merge)
```

which would show me that the the merge result, decrypted is

```
{
   "comment": "This comment was updated somehow during the merge",
   "new_key": "this new key got added during the merge"
}
```

I am not too sure if that is very clear, but I am mostly interested if this kind of encryption exists, and if yes, what words I should look online.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is technically possible to achieve what you want, but it imposes constraints on your data that are hard to meet. Being able to do this is often considered a security vulnerability.

So here is my answer, but in short it can't be done securely.

## Symmetric encryption

When you encrypt using a symmetric algorithm like AES, you encrypt data in **block** of fixed size (128 bits or 16 bytes in this case). You also have to specify a **mode of encryption**. Popular choices are GCM (Gallois Counter Mode) or CBC (Cipher Block Chaining). They require to use a random, unique **initialization vector** to bootstrap that will make every block dependent on the encryption of the blocks before it. That will make reordering blocks impossible.

But there is a mode called ECB (Electronic Code Book) where a given block is encrypted on its own, regardless of blocks around it. So with AES in ECB mode, you could swap the blocks around and they would decrypt just fine (as long as you are using the same **key**).

But there is no guarantee the reorded blocks would make sense anymore. For example, the last block might not align on a block boundary. You could have only 8 bits of data in the last block, and 120 bits of **padding**. After decryption, you could have the padding right in the middle of your message, messing it up. If you have variable length strings, you could cut them in two making the decrypted text unusable.

But if you control the protocol, you could make it so that every field length is known and aligns on a block boundary to avoid padding. Doing so introduces a **cyphertext only** attack though. Imagine one block is the amount of a paycheck. You don't know the salary of your CEO, but I bet you would be happy to take his encrypted paycheck figure and put it in *your* paycheck message. Using fixed length fields and weak mode, you introduced a security vulnerability.

## Homomorphic encryption

There is a way to do computation on encrypted data without decrypting it. It is called Homomorphic encryption. Cutting a lot of corners, you can think of it as adding "layers" on top of something already encrypted.

Whether this could work for you is hard to tell, but I think it is unlikely. I suggest you ask on https://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks a lot for the details answer! Indeed it seems like Homomorphic encryption is the only option which would not expose too much of the content itself. But not sure if that is possible. Thanks, I'll make a most on https://crypto.stackexchange.com/ to see if I get more info